# Extracting two 2-bit number from a 4-bit number using bit shifting/masking

Tags: bit-manipulation

It might sound a simple question, but I'm trying to get my understanding clear. Pls help. So, I've two numbers that i want to concatenate into a 4-bit number.

```
n1 = 4 (0b100)
n2 = 5 (0b101)
```

To concat,

```
r = n1
r = (r >> 2) | n2
```

`r` is `21` which is `10101` binary. To read the two values back -

```
res1 = (r >> 2) & 0x1f //res1 is 5
```

I'm not sure if it is even right. My understanding is that shifting 2 bits of `r` would give us binary `101` which 5. I'm not sure how to get `4`. In most cases, the reader would not know input numbers such as `4` or `5`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, `r >> 2` = ?

Comment: How is `10101` a **4** bit number?

Comment: @spectras it is `5` as well. Masking is probably not required. How to get the first `4` that's what I'm wondering.

Comment: @AdrianMole - you mean it is 5 bit. Yep, doing `Math.log2(21)` gives me `4.39` which could be 5 bit.

Comment: Why is this tagged with javascript and c++. Which language are you asking about?

Comment: @super - any language is fine. Just tagged two languages that I mostly know of.

Comment: @asyncwait The point is that the question needs to be specific. How things are done and work is going to differ from one language to another. If you want to ask about bit-shifting in general without dealing with a specific language, then don't tag any.

Comment: @super - alright sir, will remove javascript and keep c++ and bit-manipulation. I would like my answers in c++, let's just say.

Comment: how is `r = (r >> 2) | n2` concat? you give two 3-bit numbers and output a 5-bit number. One bit in r has already be destroyed by the shift

Comment: @phuclv - thx for pointing that out. My `Math.log2` was flawed. I used `Math.floor` instead of `Math.ceil`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be some misconception

```
n1 = 4 (0b100)
n2 = 5 (0b101)
```

these are 2 ***3 bit*** numbers (count the number of binary digits in the number and don't use the formula).

Furthermore assuming you want to concatenate arbitary input values with n bits you'll need 2 n bits; you cannot just take 2 values, come up with one concatenation of both and determine the number of bits required based on this concatenation; I could concatenate 2 32 bit ints representing 1 as `0b11` (2 bit) but this does not mean I can concatenate all possible 32 bit ints into a 2 bit value.

The correct concatenation of `0b100` and `0b101` is `0b100101` (= 37), not `0b10101`

In your case the computations could be rewritten as

```
constexpr uint32_t mask = 0b111;
constexpr uint32_t bits = 3;

struct Numbers
{
    uint32_t m_value1;
    uint32_t m_value2;
};

uint32_t Combine(Numbers nums)
{
    return (nums.m_value1 << bits) | nums.m_value2;
}

Numbers Extract(uint32_t value)
{
    return { value >> bits, value & mask };
}
```

Comment: thx. accepting your answer as I see your effort to write a compiling code and better explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Some points about your calculations

1. `4` and `5` both require 3 bits to store. So you can't combine them into a four bit number. You will need 6 bits for that. Even your (wrong) attempt uses 5 bits. And when "making space" for 3 bits, you have to shift by 3 bits.
2. You are shifting in the wrong direction in the first step. If you want to "concatenate" the 5 after the 4, you have to do a left shift `<<` instead of a right shift `>>`
3. Even if the first step was correct, the extraction of the value as to be the inverse operation. You are shifting in the same direction both times.
4. For extracting 3 bits with `&` you'll need a 3-bit mask, with all bits set.

So all in all, it would look something like this

Concatenation

```
n1 = 4 // (100b)
n2 = 5 // (101b)

//left shift by three bits to make space for another 3 bits
r = n1 << 3 // (100 000b)
//combine with binary OR
r = r | n2  // (100 101b)
```

Extraction

```
r = 100101b
mask = 0x7    // (000111b)
//extract the lowest 3 bits with binary AND
n2 = r & mask // (100101b & 000111b = 101b = 5)
//right shift 3 bits 
r = r >> 3    // (100b)
n1 = r & mask // (000100b & 000111b = 100b = 4)
```

Comment: thanks for the effort. Great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

The question is flawed. First of all I'm dealing with two 3-bit numbers. It is not 2-bit number as @phuclv pointed out.

```
n1 = 4 (0b100)
n2 = 5 (0b101)
```

To concat, we need to shift first number 3-bits.

```
r = n1
r = (r << 3) | n2
```

That gives us `r` as 37 which is in binary `100101`

To extract values,

```
r >> 0 & 0b111 // or 0x07
```

We're reading first 3 bits (left to right) to get the `0b101` which is `5` and to get `4` we read from 3rd bit to last bit

```
r >> 3
```